# oracle express 11g exception weird

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEE" 
("SSN" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "MANAGER_SSN" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "STREET" CHAR(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "CITY" CHAR(25) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "DEP_NO" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "NAME" CHAR(15) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "SALARY" NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "HIRE_DATE" DATE, 
 CONSTRAINT "PK_EMPLOYEE" PRIMARY KEY ("SSN") ENABLE
)
```

and when i try to insert into that table :

```
insert into employee values (1,1,"cola","beirut",1,"mohamad",1500,"7-feb-1999")
```

it says :
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
what the hell is this !!!!! why this error is happening
 " it is not a matter of small or capital letter "

Comment: Try swapping your double quotes `"` for single quotes `'`; `insert into employee values (1,1,'cola','beirut',1,'mohamad',1500,'7-feb-1999')` Double quotes are afaik reserved for quoting field/table names.

Comment: am sry my friend , i already tried that and now i tried it again and all what i got is another error :S       insert into employee values (1,1,'cola','beirut',1,'mohamad',1500,'7-feb-1999')

Comment: What error are you getting after changing the quotes?

Comment: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected   ......      isn't that weird :/

Comment: Wrote up an answer with both your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two separate problems;

- You need to quote literal strings with `'` in Oracle, double quotes are used for quoting object names for case sensitivity.
- Your database does not seem to use the `7-Feb-1999` date format by default, so you'll have to tell it which format you're using.

All in all, the query should be;

```
INSERT INTO employee 
  VALUES (1, 1, 'cola', 'beirut', 1, 'mohamad', 1500, 
          TO_DATE('7-feb-1999', 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/18b2c2/1).

Comment: the strange thing my friend is that am used to work with this 11g and am sure that the date format i applied is the default one , it is not the first time i work with this app , and now i just created another table and am inserting data normally .. except for the employee table it is not working

Comment: @KhalilIsmail Are you connecting as the same user as when using the other tables, and is the table in the same schema?

Comment: well excuse me , but after a little more checking .. it is done dude , thank you

Comment: To check your default date format, you can do 'show parameter NLS_DATE_FORMAT'.  But, in general, it's not good practice to rely on the default date format (what if someone changes it?), and you should always use TO_DATE() function while specifying an explicit date format.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, `varchar` literals are marked by single quote (`'`), not double quotes (`"`). Double quotes denote case-sensitive object names, such as columns.

Just switch your double quotes to single quotes and you'll be fine:

```
insert into employee values (1,1,'cola','beirut',1,'mohamad',1500,'7-feb-1999')
```

Comment: i got this error when switching to lower case , that is making me really crazy .... ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected